# Строку преобразовать в список, чтобы потом можно было обратиться по индексу

Tags: python-3.x

Строка:

```
^310003312
^310005818
```

Она получается из:

```
    def get_author_id(name):
        return author_by_id.get(name)

    for name in authors_a:
        author_id = get_author_id(name)
        d = "^3{}".format(author_id)
        print(d)
```

Запись встаёт друг над другом. Желаемый итог:

```
b = ['^310003312', '^310005818']
```

Чтобы позже я смогла обратиться по индексу и получить результат. Например:

```
print(b[1])
```

Получить:

```
^310005818
```

Попыталась поделить, но строка всё равно встаёт друг над другом, а не в строчку:

```
b = b.split(' ')    
['^310003312']
['^310005818']
```

И по индексу нет возможности обратиться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно решить данную задачу?

Comment: @1st Sentinel 31 Year Perl Hist, лучше бы Вы мне написали почему после сплита я не могу обратиться по индексу?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Там ведь строки разделенные символом переноса `\n`, поэтому делайте сплит по нему:

```
text = """^310003312
^310005818"""

items = text.splitlines()
print(items)  # ['^310003312', '^310005818']

# Или:
items = text.split('\n')
print(items)  # ['^310003312', '^310005818']

print(items[1])  # ^310005818
```

---

**UPD.**

```
def get_author_id(name):
    return author_by_id.get(name)

items = ["^3{}".format(get_author_id(name)) for name in authors_a]

# Или:

items = []

for name in authors_a:
    author_id = get_author_id(name)
    d = "^3{}".format(author_id)
    items.append(d)

print(items)
```

---

**PS.**

Используйте `repr()` чтобы увидеть скрытое:

```
print(repr(text))
```

Comment: я уже и с переносом, и без. Всяко крутила. Меня даже не волнует, что они друг над другом встают. Я не могу обратиться по индексу - вот, что плохо! Это строка получилась из вчерашней формулы: `d = "^3{}".format(author_id)`. Может, в этом всё дело?

Comment: @Ireen1985, мой пример вам не помог?

Comment: эти варианты я знаю. Я их применила, но толку никакого. Добавила в вопрос вчерашнюю функцию, из которой получается такая строка. Я думаю, что тут проблема в цикле for

Comment: @Ireen1985, добавил в ответ в UPD

Comment: просто ШИКАРНО!!! Спасибо огромное!!! Всё работает!!!